# Google Map not show by using Angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to use AngularJS to make a simple Google Map app. 
I am not using Google APIs like "ngMaps" or "Angular-ui". 
I have everything in very basic structure, and I can show see my google map object in the console, the problem is that nothing shows on the page

**home.html:**

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('locator',['ngRoute', 'ngMaps']); 

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){
    'use strict';

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: './partials/home.html',
            controller: 'masterCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

**masterCtrl:**

```
app
 .controller('masterCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', masterCtrl]);

function masterCtrl($scope, $window) {
 function initialize() {
  var lat = 46.87916;
  var lng = -3.32910;
  var map_id = '#map';

  var myOptions = {
   zoom : 8,
   center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
   mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  $scope.map = new google.maps.Map($(map_id)[0], myOptions);
 }
  initialize();

}
```

Comment: did u include the google map api?

Comment: Yes, I did include in my index.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, all I need to do is to add a "ng-init" to callback my initialize() function, which would initialize the map on the page.

```
<div id="map-canvas" ng-init="initialize()"></div>
```